# Customizing CP Entries section template

Tags: control-panel

First, which template does the `actionGetElements` use to generate a response?

Second, how can I customize the template for a single entry section?

Comment: What kind of customization do you want to do, specifically?

Comment: I want to add a filter and change headers.

Answer (score 2):

First, there isn't a single specific template that [ElementIndexController's](https://craftcms.com/classreference/controllers/ElementIndexController) [actionGetElements](https://craftcms.com/classreference/controllers/ElementIndexController#actionGetElements-detail) uses to return data.

It implements [IElementType's](https://craftcms.com/classreference/elementtypes/IElementType) [getIndexHtml](https://craftcms.com/classreference/elementtypes/IElementType#getIndexHtml-detail) method which [BaseElementType](https://craftcms.com/classreference/elementtypes/BaseElementType) provides a [default implementation](https://craftcms.com/classreference/elementtypes/BaseElementType#getIndexHtml-detail) of, but any [ElementType](https://craftcms.com/docs/plugins/working-with-elements) (Entry, User, Asset, custom plugin ElementType, etc.) is free to implement that method with their own logic.

Second, it sounds like you want to hack core files in the `craft/app` folder, which I definitely wouldn't recommend.

You might be able to make the modifications you're looking for with something like the [CP CSS](https://github.com/lindseydiloreto/craft-cpcss) and [CP JS](https://github.com/lindseydiloreto/craft-cpjs) plugins.